# Access Parse Server Dashboard using Bitnami VM

Tags: parsing, azure, bitnami

I have used `Bitnami VM` to deploy Parse Server on Azure but I cannot seem to be able to access Parse Server Dashboard. What URL is it available on? Do I need to open any ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. The bitnami guys were kind enough to reply to me for this topic:

```
You can launch the latest Parse version that ships the Dashboard from https://vmdepot.msopentech.com/Vhd/Show?vhdId=64574&version=66817 It could take some time to be available in the Azure Marketplace
```

So bottom line, use the image from VM depot and not the one on Azure Marketplace as it is an old one and doesn't include the Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update on this. A new version of Parse Server provided by Bitnami is now available in the Azure Marketplace. The new version does include the Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been following [Bitnami instructions](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Parse_Server)?
It states you can access the dashboard using this URL: http://[server-IP-address]/parse
This means only TCP/80 port needs to be open (on your [Network Security Group](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/) if you use one or in your [VM ACL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-acl/) if you don't).

You have now other (probably easier) options to deploy Parse Server on Azure:

- using a [dedicated ARM template](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/marketplace/partners/microsoft/parseserver/) leveraging Azure services (App Service, DocumentDB, Notification hub, ...).
- using [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-welcomes-parse-developers/) with the original Facebook/Parse version with MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It says "Access Parse Server" not "Access Parse Server Dashboard". And also I would expect some instructions on what ports to open. Normally dashboard runs on port 4040, right?

Comment: Port can be configured as explain [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard) (github). Did you follow these instructions to install/configure Parse dashboard? You'll need to open the corresponding dashboard port (TCP/4040 by default).